# How to get the message which is having less than 10 MB size from google gmail js api?

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api

I am doing some end point calls in my application. I want to fetch only that email which is having the size less than 10 MB. So is there any way to pass any query parameter to gmail end point so it'll give me only expected result?

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

This url contains the documentation for fetching the message but it's not written how to restrict the data.

Here are the performance tips(https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance) but here also it's not clear.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer? You can retrieve the mails by the size using query of `gmail.users.messages.list`. When you want to retrieve the mails with the size less than 10 MBytes, please use `smaller:10M` as the query. If you want to retrieve the mails with the size more than 10 MBytes, please use `larger:10M`. By retrieving the message IDs using this query, you can retrieve the messages by the IDs using `gmail.users.messages.get`.

The sample script for node.js is as follows. In this sample, the message IDs of mails with the size less than 10 MBytes can be retrieved.

#### Sample script :

```
const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
gmail.users.messages.list({
  userId: 'me',
  q: 'smaller:10M',
}, (err, {data}) => {
  if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
  data.messages.forEach((e) => console.log(e.id));
});
```

#### References :

- [gmail.users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)

  - You can also test the query at this page.
- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tanaike. It worked for me and you got my question in prefect way. 
Thanks again.

Comment: @Shravan Jain Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.